# Cannot see tools, add tags, or expand Hot Network Questions when using IE11

Tags: support

I was recently forced to update from IE8 browsing to IE11, and at first I found the change to be jarring and ugly, but now that I have tried it a little...I've found it to be outright obstructive and problematic.

Upon booting up SE, I found that I could not expand the Hot Network Questions - it would only jump me to the top of the page as if redirecting me to the page I was on.  Frustrated, I attempted to ask a question about this only to find that the toolbar at the top of questions, the tag window, and even the invisible "ask a question" text in the title all were gone.

Fiddling around a bit, I've found that by activating InPrivate Browsing I was able to regain access to all of these functions, but it would be incredibly inconvenient to always have to pop open an InPrivate box to use SE.

Is there any way I can regain my lost functionality in SE from this upgrade without resorting to InPrivate browsing?

Comment: Sounds like your connection is being run through a proxy via the Internet Options that is blocking the CDN.

Comment: @animuson That sounds probable.  I use SE for work to look up coding solutions and ask questions.